# "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to fix it? it happens when I try to post the photo to my facebook wall after the successful login.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        shareOnFacebook();
    }
}, {
    scope: 'publish_actions'
});

function shareOnFacebook() {
    FB.api('/me/photos/', 'post', {
        url: "<?php echo $fb_pic;?>",
        message: $("#fb_message").text().replace("<br/>", "\n")
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log('successful response ..successfully posted');
        $(".inviteshare .sendingmsg").hide();
        alert("Successfully posted on your Facebook wall");
    });
}
```

Comment: Did the user actually grant the permission to the app? Where they even asked for it (keyword: review)?

Comment: no. when it runs it opens only login popup . it does not open a dialog for get user permission to post the photos to their timeline.

Comment: And what user are you testing this with - one that has a role in the app?

Comment: i think default one..Open Graph Test User

Comment: should i review my app for get (user_photos) permission?

Comment: You need to submit every permission except the three basic ones for review, before you can ask normal users for them. The Open Graph test user however is a test user for the app, so it should be possible to ask for the permission without review. Try with your own account (that is admin of the app), and see if that changes anything.

Comment: ok thanks ji.i ll try

Comment: it does not work in test user acc too

Comment: Remove the app from the user’s settings, and try again (to rule out problems due to permissions that were declined earlier by the user.) Also, log the response object in the login callback to console and see what exactly it contains.